# Problem on external drive disk, can't get all disk size

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have a problem here.
I have a 3TB external hard drive that was having trouble working properly and the system was forcing me to format it.

After formatting, I realize that my drive now has a capacity of 2TB, and I can't recover the other part of the drive, so it's like the formatting made me lose 1TB of my hard drive.

How do I get this back?

Comment: what filesystem did you use for your hard drive? If you open `gparted`, does it show unallocated space? Is this disk MBR or GPT? What about the disk your system is installed on?

Comment: Let me try with gparted

Comment: With GParted I seen746.70 GB of unallocated space in the partition.

I tried to partition but it doesn't work, the partition option is not active

How can I partition it ?

Comment: can you paste the output of `sudo parted -l`?

Comment: It sounds like you have MBR, not gpt. MBR has a max of 2TiB. Conversion to gpt will totally erase drive, so if you have data, back that up first. You can also use gparted but must change device label or default partitioning first.
With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting.

Comment: I've don't see how to add picture in comment, I just add the output text here :

Model: WD My Book 25EE (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition table: gpt

Disk Flags : 

Number      Start          End           Size          File System Name                 
 1                17.4kB      210MB      210MB      fat32            EFI System Partition 
 2                210MB      3000GB    3000GB    fat32             My Book 

Flags
boot, esp
msftdata